# Rails has_one, include or join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I was wondering whats the best way to set up this DB structure in Rails 3...

I have a users table and a user_profiles table.
The users_table contains 'name, email, pass, login_count'; the user_profiles table contains 'avatar, address' other info etc...

When I retrieve a user I need to bring back their profile data as well and when a user edits their profile they are editing data from both tables...

Whats the best way to set up the relationships between these tables?

has_one with belongs_to, include or join.... or is there a better or standard way? What would you do?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` and `belongs_to` for you. Go through [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) to better understand it.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Will I have any probs working with predefined tables that don't use 'id' as the primary key in both tables?

Comment: Yes. Primary keys are a must. How are you planning on relationships otherwise?